# Find all functions $f \in \mathbb{C}^2[0,1]$: i. $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$; ii. $f''(x) \geq 0 \; \forall x \in (0,1)$; iii. $\int^1_0 f(x)dx = 3/2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find all functions $f \in \mathbb{C}^2[0,1]$ which is the set of all twice continuously differentiable functions on [0,1]:

1. $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$;
2. $f''(x) \geq 0 \; \forall x \in (0,1)$
3. $\int^1_0 f(x)dx = 3/2$

These conditions are separate.

Solution:

1. $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$.

I try to find polynomial functions satisfying the condition.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i$, we have $f(0) = a_0$ and $f'(0) = a_1$.

So for $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$, we only need $a_0 = a_1 = 1$.

So any polynomial function of at least degree 1 with $a_0 = a_1 = 1$ satisfies the condition.

However, how do I find all functions, not just polynomial functions satisfying the condition?

2. $f''(x) \geq 0  \; \forall x \in (0, 1)$

I try to find polynomial functions satisfying the condition.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i$, we have $f''(x) = \sum_{i=2}^n i(i-1) a_i x^{i-2} \geq 0$

Since $x \in (0, 1)$, if we choose $a_i \geq 0 \; \forall i \geq 2$, we have $f''(x) \geq 0$.

So $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i$ where $a_i \geq 0 \; \forall i \geq 2$ satisfies the condition.

However, how do I find all functions, not just polynomial functions satisfying the condition?

3. $\int^1_0 f(x)dx = 3/2$.

I try to find polynomial functions satisfying the condition.

We have $\int^1_0 f(x)dx = F(1) - F(0) = 3/2$ where $F'(x) = f(x).$

Let $F(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i$, we have $F(0) = a_0$ and $F(1) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i$

So $ F(1) - F(0) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i - a_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 3/2$

So $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i x^{i-1}$ where $ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 3/2$

However, how do I find all functions, not just polynomial functions satisfying the condition?

Comment: Although there is already a nice solution, I wanted to give another way of looking at it. As the second condition is not effected by adding a linear function to $f$, we can make a new easier problem by changing the boundary conditions. We know that the unique linear function with $f(0)=f'(0)=1$ is equal to $1+x$, so we can consider $g(x)=f(x)-1-x$. Then the conditions that are necessary for $g$ become $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, $g''(x)\geq 0$ and $\int_0^1g(x)\text{dx}=0$. Can you then prove that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Do not deface your question, especially after an answer has already been given.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question.  When you vandalize a question, you are wasting the time of the person who took the time to answer your question, and the time of anyone else who might find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

If $\ f'(0)=1\ $ and $\ f''(0)\ge0\ $ for all $\ x\in(0,1)\ $ then $\ f'(x)\ge1\ $ for all $\ (0,1)\ $ and
\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\\
&\ge1+x
\end{align}
for all $\ x\in(0,1)\ $. Now
\begin{align}
\int_0^1(f(x)-(1+x))\,dx&=\frac{3}{2}-\left[x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^1\\
&=0\ ,
\end{align}
and since $\ f(x)-(1+x)\ge0\ $ for all $\ x\in(0,1)\ $ and continous on $\ [0,1]\ $, this can only occur if $\ f(x)=1+x\ $ for all $\ x\in[0,1]\ $.